# How to detect a map (Google Maps API) loading failure?

Tags: android, api, maps, load

If I use the method "mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)" to call a map with Google Maps API, and the map cannot be loaded (server issues or no internet connection) 
How can I check if there is a failure loading the map? I want to write some actions that have to be executed only in this case.

Comment: @RumitPatel thank you but I dont know Google Maps server direction

Comment: you just need to check internet connectivity as you wrote for (server issues or no internet connection)